# how do i open a thumbnail into a new window 

Tags: javascript

I'm currently trying to populate a table with thumbnails which point to images in my server and open each in its own window when its clicked.

I can use

```
echo '<td align="center"><a href="' . $big . $newFile . '" target="_blank"><img src="' . $images . $file . '" /></a></td>';
```

which works but i want the new window to be resized. I decided to use javascript and i have a script called showImg to show my new window. The thumbnails show but when i mouseover the thumbnails i don't get the onclick functionality to work. Any leads?

The code below is what i'm trying to work with

```
echo '<td align="center"><img src="' . $images . $file .      '"onclick="showImg(this.src,400,400,"' . $big . $newFile . '");"></td>';
```

Thanks

Comment: This has absolutely nothing to do with PHP

Comment: It absolutely does. If you actually spent more than 30 seconds to think you could assume the line i posted is within a php loop. Unless you have something constructive to add, please don't comment at all

Comment: "The thumbnails show but when i mouseover the thumbnails i don't get the onclick functionality to work. Any leads?" - and by the accepted answer - nothing to do with PHP. thankyou, have a nice day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quotes issue. You can't have double quotes for both the whole onclick and the parameter of the function.

Change the PHP to:

```
echo '<td align="center"><img thumb="' . $big . $newFile . '" src="' . $images . $file .      '" onclick="showImg(this, 400, 400);"></td>';
```

Then in the JavaScript take the image source and thumbnail from the element itself:

```
function showImg(img, width, height) {
    var src = img.src;
    var thumb = img.getAttribute("thumb");
    //window.open(...)
}
```

Comment: got it to work. Thanks

You actually called the js method by sending the whole object and then retrieved the thumb from it. Smart :)